# How can I plot in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to plot the region of *0 < x<sup>2</sup> - y<sup>2</sup> <= 1*.

I have done it in [WolframAlpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WolframAlpha), and it shows like ....

[image]

How can I plot the above in LaTeX?

Comment: You should have a look at the `pgfplots` package. It has an excellent manual that will get you started. Once you have dug into it a bit, you can come back should you have more specific questions :) The manual can be found at https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf

Comment: By the way: The plot from WA is quite ugly. It tries to camouflage the symmetries of the area.

Answer (score 8):

You could do if whit `pgfplots` as [Raven](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/128658/raven) suggests or with `tikz` (there are more options too) as in my example.

I use a `\foreach` command because the region to plot and the curves are both symmetric, so I avoid repeated code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\xmax{4};
  % grid
  \draw[help lines] (-\xmax,-\xmax) grid (\xmax,\xmax);
  % axes
  \draw[-latex] (-\xmax,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [right] {$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,-\xmax) -- (0,\xmax) node [above] {$y$};
  % a little bit of the hyperbola goes out of the grid so I'm clipping it
  \clip (-\xmax,-\xmax) rectangle (\xmax,\xmax);
  \foreach\i in {-1,1} % to draw the following twice
  {%
    \draw[thick,blue,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.4] (0,0) -- (\i*\xmax,-\xmax)
          -- plot[smooth,domain=-\xmax:\xmax] ({\i*sqrt(1+\x*\x)},\x)
          -- (\i*\xmax,\xmax) -- cycle;                                   % curve(s) and yellow regoin(s)
    \draw[thick,red] (\i*\xmax,-\xmax) -- (0,0) --  (\i*\xmax,\xmax);     % asymptote(s)
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**Edit:** I changed the code a little bit, drawing the curve and filling the region at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

If you compile this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \filldraw[fill=cyan,draw=black,domain={-sqrt(3)}:{sqrt(3)},variable=\y,samples=100]
      (2,-{sqrt(3)})--(2,-2)--plot({sqrt(\y*\y+1)},\y)--(2,2)--(0,0)--(2,-2)--cycle;
    \filldraw[fill=cyan,draw=black,domain={-sqrt(3)}:{sqrt(3)},variable=\y,samples=100]
      (-2,-{sqrt(3)})--(-2,-2)--plot({-sqrt(\y*\y+1)},\y)--(-2,2)--(0,0)--(-2,-2)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

you will get this:

[image]